# Why reputation goes down after voting down?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, down-votes

Is there any reason for a reputation decrease after voting down a wrong or inappropriate answer or question?  This just annoys some users, including me!  NO one wants to lose his/her reputation at any cost.  Please, can anyone answer this?

Comment: No one wants to lose their reputation, yet you want to be able to down-vote answers (forcing those users to lose their reputation) without any limit?

Comment: Also consider that if it cost nothing to down-vote, it might work out to about the same, because then other people might be more likely to down-vote more of your answers, for the same reason you would be more willing to down-vote theirs.

Comment: The great thing is that downvoting questions is free.

Comment: oh, thanks @AaronBertrand got it!

Comment: +1 "Please can anyone satisfy me?"

Comment: @NickFreeman: You didn't upvote. -1 your comment.

Comment: @juergend I was going to down vote until I saw the last line. -1 + 1 = 0 ;)

Comment: I wish meta stackoverflow had kept a badge on getting this much downvotes :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It ensures people don't downvote answers without thinking first.

For example - when there are several answer on a question, it helps ensuring people don't downvote other "competing" answers.

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui - elaborate on what?

Comment: I wish I could downvote comments.

Comment: @DannyBeckett - You can always upvote a comment, then unupvote it (within the grace period). Not quite as satisfying though.

Comment: you could print it out, stamp on it, shred it and flush it down he toilet - may be a bit more satisfying.